# OpenCL how to save and reuse a number of commands?

Tags: c, opencl

I am new to OpenCL. I am trying to implement my own fixed pipeline renderer like that of OpenGL 1. I am using 1st version of OpenCL so I can't call any kernel inside kernel. I have created my own triangle drawing function without problem. I wanna do the parallelization of each triangle at pixel level so I need to call same kernel multiple times. Can I create a display list like the system in OpenGL 1? I can draw one triangle with

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue,k_drawTriangle,1,NULL,&global_item_size,&local_item_size,0,NULL,NULL);
```

Should I use clFlush everywhere after drawing? Or when should I use it if necessary?

How clFlush and clFinish works here? Can I save a number of commands in a seperate command queue I created and use this set of commands again and again?

Something like

```
Q = clCreateCommandQueue(context,device_id,0,&ret);

{
    int i;
        for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        CLdrawTriangleD(Q,tri2i(0,0,400,200,0,400));    
}
```

(CLdrawTriangleD includes clEnqueueNDRangeKernel containing Q)

Thus, Q indirectly defines a set of commands drawing a model, for example.

I don't wanna learn everythink about OpenCL. To summerize the question, the only thing I additionally wanna know about OpenCL is how I can save a few commands and call this same set of commands in another context? Calling Q over and over without clearing the command list.

**A better summary of the subject :**

How to enqueue multiple commands for out of order execution after a single event? How to trigger that event any time without deleting the ingredient of the command queue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're mis-understanding the OpenCL programming paradigm. OpenCL kernels are not intended for doing one small task (like drawing a single triangle); they're for doing many different instances of the same task (like drawing all the triangles in a scene), or one single large task which can be broken down into many small collaborative actions.

So, if you have 100 triangles to draw, you would call a `draw_triangle` kernel, but have, say, each work-group handle one triangle - so you have 100 workgroups with each workgroup having some relevant size to do your parallel work.

Comment: I meant every triangle is gonna use multiple cores each representing one pixel. So there is parallelization for every single triangle. When you try to do the other way around, things are getting way slower than they need to be. When you draw every triangle with one core. Each core has to draw multiple pixels, which is gonna slow down the whole process more than it should. I have tried what you have said. if you have a better way to subdivide a kernel into smaller sub kernels, you may want to talk about another OpenCL property I don't know.

Comment: @newbie_developer93: Nobody said anything about physical core assignments. A single physical core may execute multiple work-groups. Also, you can structure your grid differently, e.g. multiple triangles per workgroup or multiple workgroups per triangle - I was just giving an example. At any rate - you don't subdivide a kernel into smaller sub-kernels; it's the single kernel that does many different things.

Comment: You get what I mean by subdividing into pixels = increasing the parallelization... My question is : how can I send a set of commands to gpu and then do the execution on device side any time I want in OpenCL?

Comment: @newbie_developer93: Enqueue them after an event, then trigger the event and synch/flush the queue.

Comment: I am asking exactly how to do that.

Comment: @newbie_developer93: That's not clear from your question; can you edit it please?

Comment: I don't know how command queues and event handling works. I am asking exactly what to do to use same set of commands for device side. Ok. I edited it properly. (well, hopefully :( ) Thanks in advance